Why can I use an SSH private key with group permissions on a remote server but not on my local machine?
Introduction
There is something I don't understand with SSH private key permissions and I'd like some in-depth explanations about the difference in behavior I'm noticing
Here is the thing, I am trying to write an extensive documentation on the overthewire challenges and the question is about the level bandit13 (I am writing this only to help people that are familiar with these challenges but it is not so much focused on the challenges).
Remote host situation
I am logged in as the user bandit13 and I get an ssh key that I should use to connect as the user bandit14 on the server. Here is the output of the command stat when ran on the file "sshkey.private" :
  File: sshkey.private
  Size: 1679        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10301h/66305d   Inode: 517716      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (11014/bandit14)   Gid: (11013/bandit13)
Access: 2024-06-03 16:10:51.521532387 +0000
Modify: 2023-10-05 06:19:21.815263421 +0000
Change: 2023-10-05 06:19:21.819263430 +0000
 Birth: 2023-10-05 06:19:21.815263421 +0000

We can see that the key belongs to the user bandit14 but is also readable by the members of the group bandit13, which seems to be in conflict with this section from the ssh(1) man page :
~/.ssh/id_rsa
             Contains the private key for authentication.  These files contain sensitive data and should be readable by the user but not accessible by others (read/write/execute).  will simply ignore a
             private key file if it is accessible by others.  It is possible to specify a passphrase when generating the key which will be used to encrypt the sensitive part of this file using AES-128.

However, I can use this private key to connect to the user bandit14 by running :
ssh -p 2220 -l bandit14 -i sshkey.private localhost

Local machine situation
Now, when I retrieve the ssh key on my local machine, here is the output I get from the stat command :
  File: bandit14_sshkey
  Size: 1679        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 8913955     Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: ( 1001/ Charystag)   Gid: ( 1001/ Charystag)
Access: 2024-06-03 21:05:42.285372019 +0200
Modify: 2024-06-03 21:05:11.765802230 +0200
Change: 2024-06-03 21:05:11.765802230 +0200
 Birth: 2024-06-03 21:05:11.733802682 +0200


which also seems to contradict the same section from the ssh(1) man page.
However this time, when I try to connect to the remote host by running :
ssh -p 2220 -l bandit14 -i bandit14_sshkey bandit.labs.overthewire.orgs

I get the following banner :
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0640 for 'bandit14_sshkey' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "bandit14_sshkey": bad permissions

My Question
What can possibly explain the difference in behavior between these two situations? Please don't tell me that I should change my permissions for my ssh key on my local machine as I already know that but explain why I can jump from one user to another on the remote host.
Please ensure to link to some documentation in your answer.
What did I try to understand?
I basically read a lot of stackOverflow questions, the ssh(1) and sshd(8) man pages and asked ChatGPT 4o but I got nothing concrete so here I am.
Thanks a lot to those of you who'll come to this point and who'll take time to answer me.
Have a great day y'all

The difference
On the local machine the user who owns the key is using it and gets warned that someone else might be able to read it, too. On the remote machine the file is owned by user bandit14, but used by another user bandit13 through the group permission. The condition is ignored because bandit13 is already the "others" instead of the one that should be warned.
Explanation
This is a rather old decision, as it has been this way since September 23, 2001 after 7aff261 "relax permission check for private key files" by
Ben Lindstrom. The commit:

replaced the "or" condition (...|| (st.st_mode & 077) != 0) with an "and" condition (((st.st_uid == getuid()) && (st.st_mode & 077) != 0)) making it more relaxed,
separated the fstat(fd, &st) < 0 condition (currently fstat(fd, &st) == -1 from 4d28fa7) that should still always result in an error (SSH_ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR instead of 0 since 8668706 in 2014), and
added a comment that is still there in sshkey_perm_ok() of authfile.c.

int
sshkey_perm_ok(int fd, const char *filename)
{
    struct stat st;

    if (fstat(fd, &st) == -1)
        return SSH_ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    /*
     * if a key owned by the user is accessed, then we check the
     * permissions of the file. if the key owned by a different user,
     * then we don't care.
     */
#ifdef HAVE_CYGWIN
    if (check_ntsec(filename))
#endif
    if ((st.st_uid == getuid()) && (st.st_mode & 077) != 0) {
        error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        error("@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @");
        error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        error("Permissions 0%3.3o for '%s' are too open.",
            (u_int)st.st_mode & 0777, filename);
        error("It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.");
        error("This private key will be ignored.");
        return SSH_ERR_KEY_BAD_PERMISSIONS;
    }
    return 0;
}

Documentation?
Unfortunately, the comment on the source code seems to be the only documentation for this feature; it is not mentioned in the OpenSSH Manual Pages.
